# Error while starting Weblogic Managed Server

Tags: weblogic12c, rhel6

```
owertier.ServiceDisabled=true  weblogic.Server
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid file name for use with -Xloggc: Filename can only contain the characters [A-Z][a-z][0-9]-_.%[p|t] but it has been /var/SP/apps/weblogic12c/osbseldomain/log/gcinfo_managedserver_*.log
Note %p or %t can only be used once
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <INFO> <NodeManager> <The server 'ManagedServer_1' with process id 10159 is no longer alive; waiting for the process to die.>
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <Process died.>
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed during startup and will be retried>
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <get latest startup configuration before deciding/trying to restart the server>
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed but will not be restarted because the maximum number of restart attempts has been exceeded>
<Sep 9, 2018 11:49:49 AM GST> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <runMonitor returned, setting finished=true and notifying waiters>
:1
```

Comment: The error seems to be obvious, since it's spelled out in the message. Can you explain what is confusing you or what is keeping you from fixing it?

Comment: FIle Name is already there but still getting error...actually i have upgraded my java to jdk1.8.0_181 from jdk1.7.0_75
//var/SP/apps/weblogic12c/osbseldomain/log]$ ls -lrt gcinf* 
 -rw-r-----. 1 28919 Sep 9 14:00 gcinfo.log 
 Moreover Managed Servers are getting started from Command prompt but not getting started from console.....
gc log nomenclature settings have not been touched at all..only jdk versions have been updated

Comment: The file name contains a `*` which according to the error message is not allowed. I have no expertise in that area, but do you have any reason to believe the error message is wrong?

Comment: logger configuration have *   /var/SP/apps/weblogic12c/osbseldomain/log/gcinfo_managedserver_*.log                                                                                                                 /opt/SP/apps/config/OSBSel -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/opt/SP/config -server -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xloggc:/var/SP/apps/weblogic12c/osbseldomain/log/gcinfo_managedserver_*.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to create the JVM that's because you are using the old syntax of jvm variable with the new version of jdk.
Just change them accordingly.
 For the gc log considering the log directory already exists "*" is creating problem , not sure why you are using it. You can use date format instead to create a new log file.
gcinfo_managedserver_`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`-.log